# REGEX for UK driving license

Tags: regex

I am working on validating UK driving license using regex. But the regex does not match accurately.

example, `MORGA753116SM9IJ` is a valid driving license and it matches but if I append some random characters like `123abc` to it `MORGA753116SM9IJ123abc`, then it matches till '123abc' which is wrong.

see https://regex101.com/r/GwEJId/4

Answer (score 1):

Sandwich your regex between [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) metacharacters `\b`:

```
\b[A-Z]{1,5}[9]{0,4}[0-9]{6}[A-Z]{1,2}[9]{0,1}[0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JmAUHY/1)